# Render problem android studio как решить проблему?

Tags: android, android-studio, render

Я думаю что это уже заезженный вопрос по поводу проблемы с рендеррингом, после того как я обновил студию или это не влияет на данную проблему, по факту я знаю что визуальный редактор барахлит и это для него норма, но все-таки хочется узнать как решить данную проблему, я уже все подряд пробовал иногда помогает иногда нет, что я только не пробовал:

1. Добавлял Base в стилях.
2. Меня тему приложения, просто тупо пробовал все подряд пока не появлялись элементы в визуальном редакторе.
3. Чистил кэш и перезагружал студию.
   И ещё много танцев с бубном, какие в итоге либо решают эту проблему или нет.

Так вот может есть какие-то неизвестные мне способы и методы которые точно решат эту проблему. У меня проблемы с рендерингом есть на разных активити (empty, login, settings). Иногда помогает выбор темой приложения `Material.Light.DarkActionBar` но не всегда. Буду рад за полезные советы просто хочется разобраться так как раньше такого не было))

Comment: мое скромное мнение, что тут ничего не придумаешь. Иногда он глючит, и тогда последовательным перебором всего того, что вы описали, ты пытаешься его лечить. Если это не помогает, то пытаешься снова и попинываешь ногой бубен)))

Comment: Я помню, что в старые бородатые времена,  мы меняли api у рендера и это помогало, возможно, сама sdk этой версии глючная

Comment: чисто как вариант может быть, потому-что раньше может оно где-то и было но что-бы так явно висеть, то нет такого не было.

Comment: Попробуй rebuild project/make project. Иногда это помогает. Только перед этим закрой все файлы которые редактируешь (желательно)